# Multiplying decimals in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a tax calculator for my class and I can't figure out how to multiply a whole number with a decimal. I have to multiply the whole by 0.13. Here's my code

```
var amount:Number;
var hst:int;

amount_txt.restrict = "0-9";



calculate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculate);

function calculate(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  amount = Number(amount_txt.text);

total_txt.text = "You have spent a total of " + String(Math.round((amount * hst)) + "$") 
}
```

I would appreciate help quick, as it is due tomorrow. I apologize if the formatting on here is incorrect, but I assure you on the actual program it is correct. Thanks

Comment: Give an example of **expected output** from two input values (whole vs fractional). So your `amount = 0.13` but how much is `hst`? The default value of `int` is zero, so right now your code is doing `0.13 x 0` which gives correct `0` as result. What is the problem?

Comment: Your `hst` is int, so it can't store a 0.13. Make it `Number` and stuff 0.13 in it, should do.

Comment: @Vesper maybe `hst` is int type because it's the mysterious _whole number_? Then again, they restrict amount text to `0-9` so why not use `amount = int(amount_txt.text);`? I just hope Asker knows that `number` is for handling fractions but `int` handles whole numbers only (the decimal point is ignored).

Comment: You are using the `Math.round()` function for the output, which will always return an int. It does not, like in other languages, round to precision. If you want to round to a precision do something like `Math.round(value*n)/n` (n = 10 = 1 decimal, n = 100 = 2 decimals, n = 1000 = 3 decimals and so on). Also, make sure you have a value stored in `hst`, as VC.One already said it will be initialized with 0, therefore your result will always be zero with the given code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your HST is not a `Number` but an `int`. In order to make it a decimal number you have to change it as a `Number`

```
var amount:Number;
var hst:Number;

amount_txt.restrict = "0-9";



calculate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculate);

function calculate(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  amount = Number(amount_txt.text);

total_txt.text = "You have spent a total of " + String(Math.round((amount *hst)) + "$") 
}
```